# Can past continous fit in this example?

Tags: past-tense

> After three days of lessons, we felt more confident and we really started to enjoy ourselves. By the end of the week, we (were both falling / both fell) in love with  snowboarding and we did not want to go home.

I think ***were both falling*** is better because it is a continuous thing.  Why would ***both fell*** be correct?

Comment: What's "19" doing here? The choice between *...we both fell in love...* and *...we were both falling in love...* is just a matter of what *you* want it to mean, not what *we* think. Had the "process" of falling in love been "completed" by the end of the week or was it still onging?

Comment: By the end of the week, we had both fallen in love with snowboarding. So, were falling or had fallen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would exclude *fell*.
Given the time frame *By the end of the week...*, two valid choices would be *were falling* and *had fallen*.
Why? Because "fall in love" refers to a **transition to a state**. The process can be ongoing if it is specifically made continuous (*were falling*), but otherwise, it's a completed thing.

It's different from the first sentence, where *After three days of lessons, we felt more confident...* because *felt* refers to **a state, not a transition**.